# Check the execCommand of Selected text

Tags: javascript

I am searching for this about 3 hours !

I want to when I select a text (with mouse) from iFrame, alert that is the selected text bold or not

Answers I've found (on StackOverFlow and Other Websites) not working

Here is my code :

```
var frame = document.getElementById("iframe");
var select=frame.contentWindow.getSelection(); //get the selected text in iframe
alert(select); //alert selected text
```

I want to check `select` is bold or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` variable you got there has a property named `focusNode`.

That node has to be a text node so your text is bold if its parent node is either  a **B** node or a **strong** node.

Therefore, here's what you have to check for:

```
let tag = select.focusNode.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
let isBold = tag === 'b' || tag === 'strong'
```